# Information Management Policy not triggering to run workflow - Sharepoint 2016

Tags: workflow, 2016, timer-jobs, retention, information-policy

I'm trying to get a Workflow to run, triggered by an information policy and its simply not working. I've set up minimal test cases and they aren't working either. Here's what I've tried/tested so far.

1. Information management policy is set to run daily - and is completing with status 'successful'
2. Expiration policy is similar set to run daily, about an hour after the IMP is also successful.

I've also been testing with Run Now.

I've set up two lists for testing.

IMP test 1 has an information management policy associated with items.

[image: Snapshot of the policy]

Its set to trigger on creation + 1 day and send me an e-mail and then keep repeating every other day.

Imp test 2 is the same except the policy is associated with a test content type (IMP test) rather than a list item.

**Result**

- The List based on items doesn't do anything - Expiration date never seems to be populated with a date and the workflow isn't triggered
- The list based on content types gets an Expiration date set, but again, the workflow doesn't run.

Been banging my head against the floor for this one for a couple of weeks. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the **"Source of Retention"**? 
There are **two options** under this setting.

1. **Content Types**
2. **Library and Folders**

   - ***It should be set as "Content Types", to proceed content type based retentions.***
   - *Else the retentions of the "Content Types" will be overridden by the "Library and Folders" retentions.*

Find this option in this path: Go to "List Settings"-> "Information management and policy settings" -> Find the "Change Source" link.

If you are okay with the above and still WF not getting triggered, then please try below and let me know the result.

Set the condition as "Created Date + 0 (days)"?
And run the "Information management policy" and "Expiration Policy" timer jobs manually.

Comment: Thank you for your help @xavi. I've done as you've suggested with the content type-based list. Source of Retention is the Content Type, condition is 'Created+0 days'. Run the jobs manually in that order, with a 5 minute wait between IMP and Exp. 

'Expiration Date' is populated on item creation with today's date. However the workflow (which simply sends me an e-mail) is still not triggered.

Comment: are you sure that the "Information Management" policies are working? Please change the "Start Workflow" action to "Move Recycle bin" to confirm this. Let me know the status.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for this suggestion. On running the IMP and Exp jobs, the items are immediately transferred to the recycle bin. Switched it back to running the workflow? - not a sausage.

If I manually run the workflow from an item, the e-mail goes out. Its a Sharepoint 2010 workflow with a single email statement.

I'm still baffled. Any thoughts on where to go now @Xavi ?

Comment: Please let me know, where the related list is present? whether in the "Root Site" or in the "Sub Site".

Comment: The list is in the root of the site collection @xavi

Comment: If it is root site collection, it would be working fine. Anyhow, What are the start options in the Workflow you've checked?

Comment: Please remember to update the workflow in the retention policy, whenever you re-publish the workflow.

Comment: Yup. I’ve done that. I really appreciate your help, but do you think we are coming to the end of the line here - or are there any other lines of enquiry that spring to mind @xavi

Comment: This issue seems to be weird to me, because all the other actions are responding properly. I am sure there is no separate steps to be done for "Start Workflow" action. Final Suggestion to you, that try with new 2010 workflow/ New List. You might be tried that too..! @ChrisN

Comment: Worth a try. I’ll give it a go in the morning.

Comment: And the answer was.... The farm admins hadn't correctly updated the databases following a previous patch. Updated and the problems melted away. Grrrr. Thanks for your help @xavi

Comment: Ooooh..! Please vote, if anything useful for you.

Comment: I've upvoted @Xavi - unfortunately because I have a noob account the votes apparently don't show. I tell you what though, I quite often make small donations to charity on behalf of people who help me out. Ping me your favourite charity and I'll pop a few quid in their direction.

Answer (score 0):

All the bizarre IMP behaviours turned out to be due to the databases not being updated following a software patch. There's a life lesson there, somewhere.